# Decode ArrayBuffer on React-Native

Tags: node.js, react-native, stream, react-native-video

I'm trying to decode an ArrayBuffer on React-Native. My data is an h264 stream, but for now i write native code for Android (MediaCodec) and iOS (VideoToolBox) for decode frames, work "nice".

But i would like use JS (or library) for this, for lack of knowledge in Java / Kotlin and Objective-c.

So, i've try to convert my `ArrayBuffer` to base64 (with `base64-arraybuffer` library) and try to play it with `react-native-video`, but not result.

```
const buffer = encode(data);
const blob = new Blob([buffer], {
  type: "video/avc",
  lastModified: Date.now(),
});
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Maybe, the best is to write stream file ?

If anyone have an idea, very big thank you.

Comment: Didn't get the exact question. Do you want to create a video file URL from an array buffer or something else?

Comment: Hi Sharad ! Yes, i try to create video file to ArrayBuffer data (h264 type)

Comment: You can give a try for this

ffmpeg-kit-react-native

This library is having support for h264

Comment: Yes, i've try with this library, but it convert file to file, not raw input to file :)